# How to print top 3 employees in a region in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with three columns, region, emp_name, salaries.

I want to add one more column to this table in excel.

That new column should have either 1 or 0. 1 indicates one of the top3 employee based on salaries in a particular region.

For example, Region1 has 7 employees, namely emp1, emp2, so on emp7. emp2, emp4, emp7 have top 3 salaries.

So in the new column, emp2, emp4, emp7 must have 1 and others have 0. Let's say this table contains n number of regions.

Comment: Why put 0 or 1 when you can use `RANK()`

Comment: You can also do this in a pivot table which needs no formula

Comment: Thanks Mech, but I have n number of regions. If it has only one region, I would straight away use Rank function

Comment: urdearboy, actually my project demands me to create an extra column with the flag "1" for top3 or "0" for others. In the pivot table, I can sort it within each region, that I am aware of. Or do you have some other thought?

Comment: what if there is a tie in third place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in D2 and copy down:

```
=IF(C2>=AGGREGATE(14,7,$C$2:$C$1000/($A$2:$A$1000=A2),MIN(COUNTIF(A:A,A2),3)),1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Use a pivot table

1. Insert the pivot using your whole range
2. Add Region/Employee to `Rows` field *(In that order)*
3. Add Salary (SUM) to the `Values` field
4. Below Pivot Table Design = No Subtotals, No Grandtotals, Tabular Layout
5. Select the drop down on `Employee`, Select `Value Filter`, Select `Top 10...`
6. Complete form with `Top 3 Items by Sum of Salary`

---

If a region does not have 3 options, the top n will appear where *n < 3*.

[image]

---

If you need to use the 1, 0 option you could just do a vlookup on this table too. Note that a error will return if they are not on this list which means they are not top 3. You can use some error handling to convert this to 1, 0

Comment: @ScottCraner made a good point about showing a tie that you may want to consider. I have not tested what this will do when a tie occurs